# Using a Minitel keyboard with a modern PC

Tags: keyboards, old-hardware-adaptation

I have a problem for my next project. I want to buy a Minitel (a French terminal, ancestor of PC and Internet). Once I have it, I want to remove the old screen and everything that is inside then put a new screen and a little PC box inside it. This will be the easy part.

The hardest part is that I want to keep using the old keyboard, so I think I should find a way to put electricity into it and solder some wire to get whatever comes out of it.

This is where you guys can help me: What should I use to get the outputs of the old keyboard and code something to translate them in order to get a USB input for the new PC?

[image: Connection from a Minitel to a PC]

Comment: Same comment as you got in EE.SE: you need to figure out the electrical interface and protocol used by the old keyboard. Only after that you can start to figure out with what it can be interfaced. Do you have any information, schematics or service manual that could have this info?

Comment: Standard pedantry: the internet, which began in the 1960s, is not a descendant of the Minitel, which first came to market in 1982. Neither is the 1981 IBM PC.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rid of the crt screen? Shame... There are lots of tutorials for using minitels as terminals. Of course, graphics capabilities are more than limited, but that's the beauty of it...

Comment: @Tommy "At the beginning the Minitel had for objective to make it possible to consult a national telephone directory. Afterwards a surcharged number 3615 allowed to consult various sites such as gaming sites and messaging site. The Minitel was launched in 1980, nearly 12 years before the world wide web."

Comment: @user20439316 are you aware that the web is not the internet, and is not even the first web-style interface on the internet?

Comment: I guess the correct historical framing would be that Minitel was the French take on Compuserve, Prestel, etc. As per Wikipedia’s article on Videotex in general: “Meanwhile … the French government was determined to catch up on a perceived falling behind in its computer and communications facilities”. Although hugely significant for the scale of its deployment, in technological terms Minitel followed, it didn’t lead.

Comment: @Tommy _"Although hugely significant for the scale of its deployment, in technological terms Minitel followed, it didn’t lead."_ indeed: it's tragic that so much effort was dead-ended. Given that European videotext systems tended to be operated by (often monopolistic or state-owned) PTTS companies, and their support for [OSI+X.25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Wars) (with its _integrated billing_ features, which speaks to their hubris) I don't think it could have been possible _at all_ for any of them to lead when the post-ARPA Internet came knocking.

Comment: I wonder if you might consider adding a serial interface as at https://forum.museeminitel.fr/t/server-building/400 and using it as a simple terminal instead?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[This Instructables project](https://www.instructables.com/Old-School-Minitel-Laptop/) by [Gautchh](https://www.instructables.com/member/Gautchh/) shows how to handle the keyboard. The keyboard uses a simple matrix with a 17-wire output; pressing a key connects two of the wires. In Gautchh’s project, the matrix is decoded using an Arduino, which emulates a USB HID keyboard. The matrix is as follows:

```
      //  5   4   3   2  15  14  13   9
/* 6  */{'c','D','Q','5','r','l',' ',' '},
/* 7  */{'L','F','Y','A',',','r','s',' '},
/* 17 */{'K','G','Z','T','.','a','c',' '},
/* 16 */{'J','H','E','R','"',' ','g',' '},
/* 12 */{'V','C',';','U','e','r','s',' '},
/* 11 */{'B','X','-','I','*','4','7','1'},
/* 10 */{'P','W',':','N','O','5','8','2'},
/* 8  */{'M',' ','?','O','#','9','6','3'}};
```

[An Arduino program](https://content.instructables.com/FSV/ZJA7/KU783EA8/FSVZJA7KU783EA8.ino) is provided to handle the conversion for you. You still need to connect the Arduino to the keyboard of course!

The above matrix is partial, and corresponds to that used in the Arduino project; another site (in French) gives [a complete matrix for an Alcatel Telic Minitel 1B](https://entropie.org/3615/index.php/2020/08/05/le-clavier-du-minitel-1b/):

|  | 15 | 14 | 13 | 12 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **16** | ↑ | Correction | Annulation | ↓ | Shift | ← | → | ↲ |
| **11** | T | E | R | Y | ; | - | : | ? |
| **10** | G | D | F | H | * | 7 | 4 | 1 |
| **9** | . | Esc | , | ' | Suite | Retour | Envoi | Répétition |
| **8** | B | C | V | N | 0 | 8 | 5 | 2 |
| **7** | Guide | Z | A | Sommaire | U | I | O | P |
| **6** | Fnct | S | Q | Ctrl | J | K | L | M |
| **1** | Connexion / Fin | X | W | Espace | # | 9 | 6 | 3 |

The two matrices don’t match, so it’s possible you’ll have to figure out the matrix for whatever keyboard you have.

Comment: Why are there two Cs? At 6/5 and 12/4? There are also two Os, at 8/2 and 10/15, many spaces, and maybe other duplicates. Why are the columns and rows not in order? I feel like this answer needs more explanation about what we're looking at here. It does not look like "a simple matrix".

Comment: @OmarL: there is a lowercase and uppercase 'c', of the two capital 'O's one should probably be a '0' (zero), and the many spaces are likely unused combinations (except for the one 'real' space)

Comment: @Pelle so what are both upper and lower case doing in a keyboard matrix? Usually the matrix identifies a key, not the glyph. Also there are missing keys such as cursor movement, Ctrl, Shift, etc. And where are "Connexion Fin", "Sommaire", "Annullation", etc, are they ignored or mapped to some PC specific thing like Insert or prtscr? So the plot thickens...

Comment: @OmarL looking at the code, I guess the lowercase codes are the 'command-keys', the code maps 'r' to KEY_BACKSPACE. The rest seems to be not implemented.